# This code shows focus gained before the button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea, focuslistener

I want the GUI to show "focus gained" when the user clicks on the button and
"focus lost" when clicking anywhere else. But it always shows "focus gained".

**Main Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class focuslistener extends JFrame {

    private Container c;
    private JButton jb1;
    private Font f;
    private JTextArea ta1;

    focuslistener() {
        inticompo();
    }

    public void inticompo() {
        c = this.getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        c.setLayout(null);
        f = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 18);
        jb1 = new JButton("Clicked");
        jb1.setBounds(50, 10, 250, 80);
        jb1.setForeground(Color.red);
        jb1.setBackground(Color.blue);

        jb1.setFont(f);

        c.add(jb1);

        ta1 = new JTextArea();
        ta1.setFont(f);
        ta1.setBounds(10, 110, 400, 300);
        ta1.setForeground(Color.black);
        ta1.setBackground(Color.red);

        c.add(ta1);
        jb1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                ta1.setText("focus Gained");
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                ta1.setText("focus Lost");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        focuslistener a = new focuslistener();
        a.setVisible(true);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.setBounds(50, 100, 500, 500);
        a.setTitle("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need something that can gain focus from the button - try clicking on the text field

Comment: That code [works here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOVkf.png). **General Tips:** 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. ..

Comment: .. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: You seem to have at least two misunderstandings about focus: 1) The button becomes focused as the GUI appears because it is the *first* focusable component in a GUI with just two (the other being the text area). 2) The button will *not lose focus* when clicking other non-focusable area of the test app. But the button *will lose focus* if the user clicks (or tabs to) the text area, or clicks another open app etc. --- Perhaps the requirement(1) here would be better fulfilled with a `MouseListener`. 1) Rquirmnt I'm not clear on. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: @AndrewThompson i think i fell into the XY trap.thanks for mentioning that term.I know button will only lose focus when the user clicks (or tabs to) the text area(i'm sorry i could mention the exact problem before).but my question was how can i avoid to get the message "focus gained" at first when i run the program(when i will click on the button then it will show "focus gained").i used MouseListener. now it is working as i wanted.thank you for all these information .You are great!